# Convert CollectionView.CurrentItem as a DataRow?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to convert MSDN's video on "[How Do I: Create a Simple Data Entry Form in WPF?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/vstudio/cc707833.aspx)" in VB to C#. I'm stuck at 20:11.

I start by creating a Typed DataSet and a CollectionView:

```
private CustomerDataSet CustomerData = new CustomerDataSet();
private CustomerDataSetTableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter taCust = new CustomerDataSetTableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter();
private CustomerDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager taManager = new CustomerDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager();
private CollectionView View;

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.taCust.Fill(this.CustomerData.Customers);
    this.DataContext = CustomerData.Customers;

    this.View = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.CustomerData.Customers);
}
```

I wired navigation buttons fine. My trouble began when I wired the Delete button's event. According to MSDN's [CollectionView.CurrentItem documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.currentitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I should be able to convert the CurrentItem to another object. I want to convert CurrentItem to a DataRow (or a Typed DataRow) so I can call the DataRow's Delete method.

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.View.CurrentPosition != -1)
    {
            // This doesn't work, throws null exception:
            // DataRow row = this.View.CurrentItem as DataRow;
            // 
            // This doesn't work either, throws null exception: 
            // CustomerDataSet.CustomersRow row = this.View.CurrentItem as CustomerDataSet.CustomersRow;
            MessageBox.Show("row:" + row.ToString());
     }
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you try checking which part of `this.View.CurrentItem` is `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the row like this,

```
DataRow row = (this.View.CurrentItem as DataRowView).Row;
```

Comment: Thank you, Neel! Can you explain how this works (it does) or link me to a site where I can read more?

Comment: `CurrentItem` is actually returning `DataRowView` object NOT the `DataRow` object, so I just cast it to `DataRowView` which has a property `Row` which returns the underlying `DataRow` object. For more information check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ss7fbaez(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I meant to thank you, Sallushan. Thanks very much for the additional information!